# Iframe only loads content on 2nd click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe which is being loaded from a second url, and opening as a print window, in order to generate and print an invoice.

However the content will only appear the 2nd time I click the Invoice button, not the first. I've tried adding a timeout to the function but it has no effect.

```
<button type="button" onClick="$('#order_invoice').attr('src','/default.aspx/[url goes here');setTimeout(window.frames['order_invoice'].print(),500);" class="major" title="Tax Invoice">Tax Invoice</button>
                        <iframe id="order_invoice" name="order_invoice" class="order_invoice" src="" style="display:none;" scrolling="no"/>
```

When I click the button I get a blank page in the print preview, how can I delay the window opening until the content is loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it's very early here and I'm not quite awake yet.

Comment: iframes have a load event that can be used for your purpose

Answer (score 0):

The best way to control such things is to put print functionality into function on the parent page, than to call this function from child iframe as parent.myFunction() from document.onLoad function of the child.